# ¿Como podria hacer un gridView con elementos expandibles?

Tags: android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buen dia.

Como podria lograr esta funcioanlidad en un gridView, la cual es que al seleccionar un item del gridview se expanda (inserte una nueva fila) debajo de la seleccion?.
De antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿Una nueva fila de lo mismo? ¿O que muestre un detalle del correspondiente?

Comment: Si correcto, un detalle del item seleccionado

Answer (score 0):

Mira me estoy yendo a dormir, asi que te hice esto rapido

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDetalle1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Hola"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDetalle2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Hola"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDetalle3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Hola"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDetalle4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Hola"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDetalle5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Hola"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Simulas un Grid con Linear Layouts 
Hice filas con botones que ocupan el mismo espacio
y debajo de cada fila puse un layout detalle con la visibilidad en GONE
Eso hara que el layout no se vea, que sea como si no existiera .
Lo que haras tu, sera desde el codigo, ponerle un OnClick a cada boton, y mandar a cambiarle la visibilidad al layout que este debajo de su respectiva fila y al layout detalle puedes meterle todo lo que quieras , en el ejemplo puse un textView, bueno , pues al hacerlo visible, podras pasarle datos a los items , los llenas conforme el boton correspondiente et voila mon ami! , asi con cada fila y cada boton, si no quieres botones puedes poner otras cosas, solo les pones un OnClick , usa la imaginación , no te rindas.

Alli acomodas todo para que se parezca mas a lo que quieres de Grid , el truco aqui son los layouts con Visibility : "GONE"

Ya desde el Main Activity agarraras algo como

boton.OnClick ... bla bla bla {
layoutDescripcion1.setVisibility(VIEW.VISIBLE);
}
Si quieres volver a ocultar uno utiliza VIEW.GONE 
y asi mi amigo, me voy a dormir, de nada.

Comment: Divierteté! que esto del diseño es super divertido.